# Set Images on various ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

So look, I have 6 ImageViews and have ActivityOnResult to take Pictures from gallery and camera.

Each ImageView have the Onclick Method so when they are pressed they call a dialog with the options to choose.

I can't find the way to asign the image to the correct ImageView, say if you click the third ImageView the picture selected is then Set on the third ImageView.

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PHOTO_CODE:
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                            new String[]{mPath}, null,
                            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);

                                }
                            });
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                    Uri imagenFoto = Uri.parse(makeBitmapPath(bitmap));
                    Imagenes imagenesfoto = new Imagenes(imagenFoto);
                    imagenesfoto.guardar(this);
                    break;
                case SELECT_PICTURE:
                    Uri path = data.getData();
                    Imagenes imagenes = new Imagenes(path);
                    imagenes.guardar(this);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can declare another Imageview variable , assign it the id of the calling Imageview in your onclick function , now use this variable to set the Image  on the calling imageview in your OnActivityResult.
**Edit** make this variable Global.

Comment: can you show how to do this? i tried but only got a NullPointerException, guess i'm doing something wrong

Comment: I'll need to see how you are handling onclick calls , can you put that piece of code here.